# ADF add quotes to all fields

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do a copy activity in Azure Data Factory, here is how the data looks

Source: Dynamics 365 entity

```
A(GUID) | B(boolean) | C(string)
04741b89-3d51-ea11-a811-000d3af427b4| False | "some text"
```

Sink: Azure Blob delimited text file

```
A(string) | B(string) | C(string)
04741b89-3d51-ea11-a811-000d3af427b4| False | "some text"
```

I have set the sink mapping in copy activity to string. But the result does not add quotes to the values of A and B field.

Expected result:

```
"04741b89-3d51-ea11-a811-000d3af427b4"| "False" | "some text"
```

How can i add quotes to field A and B?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a copy activity to json file first and then using the json file to copy to delimited text.

[image]

Comment: Hi @prvn, I'm glad you resolve it. you can accept(mark) it or mine as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Does this not write to disk twice? It seems like a workaround only for small amounts of files, or am I wrong

Answer (score 0):

**How can I add quotes to field A and B?**

Since you already have double quote in column data, I would suggest you using single quote:

Sink dataset settings:
[image]

Sink:
[image]

Then the output file would be like:
[image]

This will add quote to all the fields, include the first row.

Hope this helps.